# Is $\left\lfloor{a}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor{b}\right\rfloor \ge \left\lfloor{a-b}\right\rfloor$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am suspecting that this is not always true.  The reason is that I do not see this inequality as a standard part of the [floor function properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Still, I could not find counter examples and I did find the following argument which suggests that it is true:

Let $\{a\} = a - \lfloor{a}\rfloor$

Let $\{b\} = b - \lfloor{b}\rfloor$

$1 > \{b\} - \{a\} > -1$

$\lfloor{a} \rfloor - \lfloor{b}\rfloor = \lfloor\lfloor{a}\rfloor - \lfloor{b}\rfloor\rfloor \ge \lfloor\lfloor{a}\rfloor - \lfloor{b}\rfloor + (\{b\} - \{a\})\rfloor = \lfloor{a - b}\rfloor$

Is it always true?  Did I make a mistake in my argument?

Comment: This can be rewritten as $\lfloor x+y\rfloor \geq \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor$. That might make it a little more obvious.

Comment: Thanks very much!  So, it is a standard rearrangement of a standard property! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Show $\lfloor x+y\rfloor \geq \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor y\rfloor$.

Then let $x=b,y=a-b$.

Comment: Very clear!  Thanks very much.